# How to send variables in jquery.post

Tags: jquery, post

I have this object I want to send:

```
var DATE={"nume":nume,"descriere":descriere,"id_sertar":tempId};
```

And I am using this function:

```
$.post("http://students.info.uaic.ro/~calin.chifan/api/compartiment/sertar/add.json",JSON.stringify(DATE),function(data){
      alert(data);
    });
```

But is not working well. How can I fix this?

Comment: directly send DATE without stringing it

Comment: Is this script served by the domain `http://students.info.uaic.ro/` (i.e. is it the same domain)? If not, does the server implement CORS? If not, you cannot make a POST request to the server (from client-side JavaScript).

Comment: The server says: the variable name was not enterd, or something like that

Comment: As a general note: Please include exact errors, not *"or something like that"*. You're a developer, not a user.

Comment: whether the server is expecting request parameter or the values as request body

Answer (score 1):

If your page is on same server then just don't stringify your DATE

```
$.post("http://students.info.uaic.ro/~calin.chifan/api/compartiment/sertar/add.json",DATE,function(data){
      alert(data);
    });
```

If your page is on different server then use server side scripting(like php Curl) with ajax to get data

Answer (score 0):

Very simple:

```
$.post(
"http://students.info.uaic.ro/~calin.chifan/api/compartiment/sertar/add.json",
DATE,function(data){
 alert(data);
});
```